# IgniteException : Spring XML configuration path is invalid

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ignite

Getting the following exception in intelliJ.

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: 
Spring XML configuration path is invalid: example-ignite.xml. 
Note that this path should be either absolute or a relative local file system path, relative to META-INF in classpath or valid URL to IGNITE_HOME.
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your configuration bean's definition has `abstract=true` parameter, try removing it if it does.

I think, the problem is that `example-ignite.xml` file has only abstract `IgniteConfiguration`. This is the case in the default configuration file in examples.

Comment: "example-ignite.xml" file don't have abstract properties, so i have to add abstract properties under beans bucket?


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!-- Imports default Ignite configuration -->
    <import resource="example-default.xml"/>

    <bean parent="ignite.cfg"/>
</beans>

Comment: Better edit the post with example-ignite.xml, bean configuration, IgniteConfiguration code in your question. We can't guess ! ;)

Comment: fine, i solved that problem. The thing is that i try to re-open the ignite instance (handle) second time in my code. I fix that by passing and using the initially created ignite instance all over the code.  Anyway thanks for your quick response @smilyface

Comment: Great ! You may add your fix as an answer here itself. It would help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. my issue was due existing error in config.xml file. for test, i ignore config.xml from environment variable (-v) and run ignite without it and after i saw that it worked, i figured out that issue is cause that.
i worked with ignite in docker in linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed with fake solution, , i used config file by internet path and not local file system path. i set config.xml on one domain path (https://example.net/config.xml) and then i set this path for spring xml configuration path.